# Access to lounge facilities at Istanbul airports?

Tags: isl, lounges, saw

I have a nine hour layover and an Amex Gold Card.

Does the card give me access to lounge facilities at Istanbul airports, even if I have to pay for the facilities?

Comment: Which country issued your card, and is it a paid-for Gold Chargecard, or just some random gold coloured credit card?

Comment: The UK Amex Good comes with two Lounge Club passes per annum (rather stingy if you ask me). Anyway, you should check the Lounge Club website. You'll need the Lounge Club card, the Amex card itself is insufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Istanbul is served by 2 airports, Istanbul Ataturk Airport (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen International Airport (SAW).

**Istanbul Ataturk Airport (IST)**

There are quite a number of lounges, you can find info listed on the [official website](http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/airportguide/Pages/Lounges.aspx).

There doesn't appear to be any Amex lounges.

Primeclass lounges offer walk-in admission which have [prices listed on this page](http://www.primeclass.com.tr/en/Pages/Istanbul-Ataturk-Airport-Service-Prices.aspx).

More info from [SleepingAirports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/airport-lounges/istanbul-ataturk-airport/index.htm)

**Sabiha Gokcen International Airport (SAW)**

Lounges are listed on their [Official page](http://www.sabihagokcen.aero/passengers-and-visitors/our-services/cip-and-lounges/lgm-cip-lounge-en).

[SleepingAirports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/istanbul_sabiha.htm) lists the following information:

> If you are an economy class traveller, you can enter these lounges at
>   Istanbul Sabiha airport either by purchasing a day pass or through a
>   membership program. Visit the individual lounge page for more details
>   (ie. facilities, hours, pass and membership information):
>
> - **LGM Domestic CIP Lounge** - Location: Domestic Terminal, Airside, upper level. Free WiFi. Hours: open 24 hours. Lounge Access: Pay at the Door (35 TL) • Priority Pass.
> - **LGM International CIP Lounge** - Location: International Terminal, Airside, upper level. Free WiFi. Hours: open 24 hours. Lounge Access: Pay at the Door (45 TL) • Priority Pass.
>
> Additionally, there are three member/cardholder lounges: THY CIP •Wings Lounge.

I have been to the lounge at SAW (I think it was the LGM International one, but can't be sure) and there were only couches to sit, nowhere to sleep.